# custom header is not supporting in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using custom header `"CLIENT-ID":"company"` in my angular2 with jax rs in backend. I have fixed `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and all `CROS` related issue in backend server if i used postman it work find but when i tried to access with angular form, it is giving me issue

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/parkgarau-ws/rest/login. (Reason: missing token ‘client-id’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
```

I dont know what is the issue, in server client-id return null and provide option respoonse 200 with no reponse body

here is my angular code

```
login(loginUser: LoginUser) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(loginUser));
    console.log(UrlConfig.BASE_URL + UrlConfig.LOGIN);
    return this._http.post(
        UrlConfig.BASE_URL + UrlConfig.LOGIN,
        JSON.stringify(loginUser),
        this.getHeaderInfo(loginUser.companyCode)
    )
        .map((response: Response) =>
            response.json()
        );

}
private getHeaderInfo(companyCode: string) {
    let headers = new Headers(

        );
    headers.append("CLIENT-ID",companyCode);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
    console.log(headers);
    return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
}
```

here is my http request and response

```
Request URL:http://192.168.0.108:8080/parkgarau-ws/rest/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:192.168.0.108:8080
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin,accept,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:151200
Allow:POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 16 Feb 2017 16:00:53 GMT
Server:Apache TomEE
x-responded-by:cors-response-filter

Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, client-id, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.0.108:8080
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: It appears that the "client-id" is not received by your backend. It may be due to the caps, but it's a guess from what I can see here

Comment: no i have tried small letter too